# how to access asp.net checkbox control in repeater for update panel trigger?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using an update panel. There are lots of checkbox in repeater and I want to use an update panel trigger but I can't access the checkbox control. How can I access it?

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="up" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="checkbox1"
            EventName= "CheckedChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Where is the repeater and the checkboxes?

Comment: @Tim : repeater is in the content template also checkbox is in the repeater. The code was too long so i have to write shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A control that the [`AsyncPostBackTrigger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.asyncpostbacktrigger.aspx) control references must be in the same naming container as the update panel for which it is a trigger. Triggers that are based on controls in other naming containers are not supported.

You can use [`ScriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerasyncpostbackcontrol.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this code in `ItemCreated of repeater`

```
ScriptManager scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this);
var cbx = (CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("checkbox1") ;
if(cbx != null)
{
    cbx.CheckedChanged+= CheckBox1_CheckedChanged;
    scriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(cbx);
}
```